"(35) OpenSSL/3.0.8: error:0A00010B:SSL routines::wrong version number" on nginx server
I have been working on trying to configure an nginx server to run my Svelte application on an aws ec2 instance for about a week now with varying success. I am no expert with nginx, so I'm sure there is just some small detail I am missing, which will make me cry when I see it.
tldr:
I am getting the error (35) OpenSSL/3.0.8: error:0A00010B:SSL routines::wrong version number when trying to curl -v my domain name (which is linked up to the aws box with a valid ssl), and I can't figure out why I am getting this.
First, I know from this post that this means that the server is responding with something other than https (likely http) when the client is expecting https. However, that post does not explain why it is doing that. I'll provide my current config file I am using here :
upstream sveltekit {
  server 127.0.0.1:3000;
  keepalive 8;
}


server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.fr www.domain.fr;

    # Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name domain.fr www.domain.fr;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.fr/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.fr/privkey.pem; # managed by certbot

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_pass http://sveltekit;
        proxy_redirect off;

        error_page 502 = @static;
    }
    location @static {
        try_files $uri /index.html =502;
    }
}

Simplified version to test https that still doesnt work:
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name domain.fr;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.fr/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.fr/privkey.pem;
    
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;


    location / {
        return 200 'SSL is working';
        add_header Content-Type text/plain;
    }
}


Here is my nginx.conf (it is default except for one import statment):
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 4096;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

}


I know that the domain name, SSL, and firewall/security groups are set up properly because it was simply working fine yesterday. The server was properly set up to forward traffic from port 443 to port 3000 (which is where my svelte app is running), and I could see my site on the web.
I will make a list of the most likely questions that will be asked:

sudo nginx -t tested successful
There are no errors in /var/log/nginx/error.log
I have been running sudo systemctl restart nginx every time I change the config file
There is nothing in the conf.d or default.d folders.
There is nothing other than nginx listening on port 443.
Even though this doesn't look like an issue with the svelte app, I know it is also working because I can curl localhost:3000 and get the correct response.
sudo openssl s_client -connect domain.fr:443 and sudo openssl x509 -in /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.fr/fullchain.pem -text -noout ran fine.

I would appreciate any help I can get, I'm starting to get a concussion from bashing my head against this. If any other information would help please let me know what to include.
